# Как расположить объекты на экране JavaFX

Tags: javafx

У меня есть панель вкладок(TabPane) которую я помещаю на сцену.
В эту панель я добавляю вкладку, которую беру из метода:

```
public static Tab fileManagementTab (){
        Tab tab = new Tab("FileManagementTab");
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        Button button = new Button("Submit");
        button.setLayoutX(400);
        button.setLayoutY(400);

        textField.setLayoutX(200);
        textField.setLayoutY(200);

        Group group = new Group(textField,button);
        tab.setContent(group);
        return tab;
    }
```

Сам метод start:

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        tabPane.getTabs().add(GraphicController.fileManagementTab());
        Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane,1200, 800);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Title");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Как видно в методе fileManagementTab я задаю расположение объектов textField и button с помощью метода setLayoutX,setLayoutY. Но при запуске программы я вижу:
[image: Программа]

Кстати так происходит только если я меняю положение 2+ объектов. То есть если я буду задавать положение только текстового поля или только кнопки, они будут именно там где мне нужно.
Собственно вопрос, почему не работает как должно и как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 0):

Group не использует размещение (Layout)  для его подкомпонентов . Все компоненты находятся в координатах (0,0). Возьмите контейнер Pane, в нем все размещается по координатной сетке.